# How to turn off Soap Message CXF form STDOUT using logback

Tags: java, logging, soap, cxf, logback

I'm working on web service using Apache cxf but in my console and catalina.out I had a lot of extra logs ,I'm using logback for logging.

I want to turn off logging soap message generated by org.apache.cxf.services,this my logback configuration :

```
<!-- Standard Output logger -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<!-- File Appender -->
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/logs/output-log.log</file>
        <triggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/logs/output-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%-10.10t]
                %60.60c:%-3L%m%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

<logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="AUDITTRAIL" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <!-- appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" / -->
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor" level="ERROR"
        additivity="false" />
    <logger name="org.apache.cxf.services" level="ERROR" additivity="false" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="AUDITTRAIL" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <!-- appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" / -->
    </root>
```

Using this configuration I still get soap message in my console log and outlog file example :

```
 mars 30, 2018 9:55:00 AM org.apache.cxf.services.WebServiceImplService.StartImplPort.WebService
INFOS: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 5
Address: http://127.0.0.1:8089/glsid/ws/webService
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Accept=[text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, 
.......
```

Any help to fix this problem thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally this solution work for me :

in the file :  `META-INF/cxf/org.apache.cxf.Logger`

I added : `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Slf4jLogger`

In the spring configuration : applicationContext :

I added :

```
 <bean id="loggingInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor"/>
    <bean id="loggingOutInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor"/> 
    <cxf:bus>
     <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingInInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <ref bean="loggingOutInterceptor"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>  
    </cxf:bus>
```

and to turn off soap logging in STDOUT in the logback.xml :

```
<!-- Apache CXF logger -->
      <logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="INFO"/>
      <logger name="org.apache.cxf.interceptor" additivity="false">
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" /> -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
      </logger>

    <root level="INFO">
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />-->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
```